Unable to run pingfederate docker container on EC2 - Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9999 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
I want to run a the pingfederate docker container on EC2. I have launched an Amazon Linux instance.
I installed docker and also copied my evaluation license on to the running instance.
The container loads the license and starts successfully using the --volume flag to mount it on the container.
I have created inbound rules to expose ports 9999 and 9031
Inbound rules:
- Type: Custom TCP Rule
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 9999
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

- Type: Custom TCP Rule
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 9999
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

I have checked port binding on the container with this:
sudo docker exec -it pingfederate netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 

However, the server fails to start. Here's a short snippet of the error log. I have the full log on github gist here:
Tailing log files (/opt/out/instance/log/server.log)

Starting server in foreground: (/opt/out/instance/bin/run.sh )
----- Starting hook: /opt/staging/hooks/80-post-start.sh
INFO: waiting for healthy admin before post-start..
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9999 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 2.80G
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9999 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
/opt/out/instance/log/server.log:  2024-07-11 16:28:21,780  INFO  [com.pingidentity.appserver.jetty.PingFederateInit] Current Directory: /opt/.
/opt/out/instance/log/server.log:  2024-07-11 16:28:21,795  INFO  [com.pingidentity.appserver.jetty.PingFederateInit] 

Why does it fail to connect? I am able to run the container on my Mac.
